# could not load library "$libdir/repmgr_funcs": ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/repmgr_funcs": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, shutdown

I am planning to move data from postgres 9.3 to 9.6, in 9.3 its has repmgr 3.0.1 configured.
tried to do pg_upgrade from 9.3 to 9.6 with out repmgr configured in 9.6, thrown error as

*could not load library "$libdir/repmgr_funcs":
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/repmgr_funcs": No such file or directory*

I tried to configure repmgr 3.0.1 on postgres 9.6.
But doing so pg_upgrade failed, which states error at starting postgres 9.6

*FATAL:  could not load library "/usr/local/pgsql-9.6/lib/repmgr_funcs.so": /usr/local/pgsql-9.6/lib/repmgr_funcs.so: undefined symbol: RequestAddinLWLocks
LOG:  database system is shut down*

Comment: "I tried to configure repmgr 3.0.1 on postgres 9.6"  What does that mean?  What commands did you run?

Answer (score 2):

PG 9.6.0 release notes says:

> The RequestAddinLWLocks() function is removed, and replaced by
> RequestNamedLWLockTranche(). This allows better identification of
> custom LWLocks, and is less error-prone.

Due to this incompatibility with PG you cannot use the repmgr version that worked on PG 9.3 with PG 9.6.

You need to upgrade to a more recent repmgr version and because repgmr 3 is no more supported you should use repgmgr 4.

Comment: Thanks for detail. So i cant perform pgupgrade since lib mismatch